# Sortable Data Grid (Enhanced Lightning Grid) - Error: Invalid datasource. Encountered runtime exception in Apex class: [sortablegrid.sdgProperties]

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, enhanced-lightning-grid

I am consistently receiving the following error when deploying flexipages to other sandboxes:

Error: Invalid datasource. Encountered runtime exception in Apex class: [sortablegrid.sdgProperties]

We are using records in each environment to configure the sortable data grid. They look to be the same across all the environments so I don't believe it has to do with that.

Wondering if this could be related to deploying too many flexipages at one time?

Comment: The Sortable Data Grid extension requires a matching `sortablegrid__SDG__c` record if you are using "Advanced Mode" (i.e., Data Provider is NOT "Relationship" in the component config). Have you set up the record in the target org?